# In a list of objects, how can you get the object when you only have the unique name of the object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of objects and I am trying to return the object in the `arrayList` whose `.getName() == target`

```
if(arrayList.contains(target)){
    System.out.print(arrayList.get(target));
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing string then use `String.equals()` method..

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: What has your code got to do with your goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your objects are of type `Foo`:

```
for (Foo item : arrayList) {
    if (item.getName().equals(target)) return item;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
int index = list.indexOf(elementToBeMatched);
    if (index != -1) {
        // Match found. Use this index
    } else {
        // match not found
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); ++i) {
  if (arrayList.get(i).equals(target))
    return i;
}
```

or better:

```
arrayList.indexOf(target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
arrayList.get(arrayList.indexOf(target))
```

Your need to check -1 condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arrayList.contains(target)){
   System.out.print(arrayList.get(arrayList.indexOf(target)));
}
```

Comment: So if `target` is in this list, why bother to use `get()` and `indexOf()`?. The rest of the method calls aren't needed.

Comment: I was just trying to fix OP's code :) You are right that the method calls are redundant when it comes to actual behavior, but hopefully it has some learning value as to how get and indexOf works.